# listen to multiple socket with websockets and asyncio

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I am trying to create a script in python that listens to multiple sockets using websockets and asyncio, the problem is that no matter what I do it only listen to the first socket I call.
I think its the infinite loop, what are my option to solve this? using threads for each sockets?

```
  async def start_socket(self, event):
    payload = json.dumps(event)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    self.tasks.append(loop.create_task(
        self.subscribe(event)))

    # this should not block the rest of the code
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


  def test(self):
    # I want to be able to add corotines at a different time
    self.start_socket(event1)
    # some code
    self.start_socket(event2)
```

Answer (score 6):

this is what I did eventually, that way its not blocking the main thread and all subscriptions are working in parallel.

```
def subscribe(self, payload):
    ws = websocket.WebSocket(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
    ws.connect(url)
    ws.send(payload)
    while True:
        result = ws.recv()
        print("Received '%s'" % result)

def start_thread(self, loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

def start_socket(self, **kwargs):
    worker_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    worker = Thread(target=self.start_thread, args=(worker_loop,))
    worker.start()

    worker_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.subscribe, payload)


def listen(self):
    self.start_socket(payload1)
    # code
    self.start_socket(payload2)
    # code
    self.start_socket(payload3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code appears incomplete, but what you've shown has two issues. One is that [`run_until_complete`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_until_complete) accepts a coroutine object (or other kind of future), not a coroutine function. So it should be:

```
# note parentheses after your_async_function()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(your_async_function())
```

> the problem is that no matter what I do it only listen to the first socket I call. I think its the infinite loop, what are my option to solve this? using threads for each sockets?

The infinite loop is not the problem, asyncio is designed to support such "infinite loops". The problem is that you are trying to do everything in one coroutine, whereas you should be creating one coroutine per websocket. This is not a problem, as coroutines are very lightweight.

For example (untested):

```
async def subscribe_all(self, payload):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # create a task for each URL
    for url in url_list:
        tasks.append(loop.create_task(self.subscribe_one(url, payload)))
    # run all tasks in parallel
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def subsribe_one(self, url, payload):
    async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(payload)
        while True:
            msg = await websocket.recv()
            print(msg)
```

Comment: await asyncio.gather(*tasks), gives me a RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'subscribe_all' was never awaited (the async function isnt executed)....its working if i use run_until_complete(gather(..)) but its blocking the thread and the code after it isn't executed

Comment: @joseRo It's hard to tell what's going on without the rest of the code. You should probably be awaiting `subscribe_all` from another coroutine...

Comment: @joseRo And who calls `test()`?

Comment: another file, just import and call it.

Comment: @joseRo I mean in the context of asyncio - is the caller an `async def` or an ordinary function? Is the event loop already running or will someone run it later?

Comment: regular function, the event loop is started in start_socket func (the code i attached)

Comment: @joseRo `start_socket` does *not* start the event loop, it just creates a task. By "starting the event loop", I mean who calls `run_until_complete` or `run_forever`, and is the event loop already running by the time `test()` is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

One way to efficiently listen to multiple websocket connections from a websocket server is to keep a list of connected clients and essentially juggle multiple conversations in parallel.

E.g. A simple server that sends random # to each connected client every few secs:

```py
import os
import asyncio
import websockets
import random 

websocket_clients = set()

async def handle_socket_connection(websocket, path):
    """Handles the whole lifecycle of each client's websocket connection."""
    websocket_clients.add(websocket)
    print(f'New connection from: {websocket.remote_address} ({len(websocket_clients)} total)')
    try:
        # This loop will keep listening on the socket until its closed. 
        async for raw_message in websocket:
            print(f'Got: [{raw_message}] from socket [{id(websocket)}]')
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError as cce:
        pass
    finally:
        print(f'Disconnected from socket [{id(websocket)}]...')
        websocket_clients.remove(websocket)

async def broadcast_random_number(loop):
    """Keeps sending a random # to each connected websocket client"""
    while True:
        for c in websocket_clients:
            num = str(random.randint(10, 99))
            print(f'Sending [{num}] to socket [{id(c)}]')
            await c.send(num)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        socket_server = websockets.serve(handle_socket_connection, 'localhost', 6789)
        print(f'Started socket server: {socket_server} ...')
        loop.run_until_complete(socket_server)
        loop.run_until_complete(broadcast_random_number(loop))
        loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        loop.close()
        print(f"Successfully shutdown [{loop}].")
```

A simple client that connects to the server and listens for the numbers:

```py
import asyncio
import random
import websockets

async def handle_message():
    uri = "ws://localhost:6789"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        msg = 'Please send me a number...'
        print(f'Sending [{msg}] to [{websocket}]')
        await websocket.send(msg)
        while True:
            got_back = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"Got: {got_back}")

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(handle_message())
```

Mixing up threads and `asyncio` is more trouble than its worth and you still have code that will block on the most wasteful steps like network IO (which is the essential benefit of using `asyncio`).

You need to run each **coroutine** asynchronously in an **event loop**, call any blocking calls with `await` and define each method that interacts with any **awaitable** interactions with an `async`

See a working e.g.: https://github.com/adnantium/websocket_client_server